# Docker - run Dockerfile before or after composer an how?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

via a docker-compose.yml i compose a mssql.

```
version:          "3"
services:
    db:
        image:        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
        environment:
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=SecretPassword
            - MSSQL_PID=Express
            - MSSQL_LCID=1031
            - MSSQL_COLLATION=Latin1_General_CI_AS
            - MSSQL_MEMORY_LIMIT_MB=8192
            - MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=true
            - TZ=Europe/Berlin
        ports:
            - 1433:1433
            - 49200:1433
        volumes:
            - ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data
            - ./backup:/var/opt/mssql/backup
        restart:      always
```

this works fine.

But how can i expand this image?
with: **mssql-server-fts**

on github i find this - but how can i combine a docker-compose.yml with a Dockerfile ?
https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-agent-fts-ha-tools/Dockerfile

Answer (score 5):

Here is a documentation on the docker-compose.yml file [docker-compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)

To use the Dockerfile in the docker-compose.yml, one needs to add the `build` section. If the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are in the same directory section of the docker-compose.yml would look like the following:

`version: '3'
    services:
      webapp:
       build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile`

`contex` is set to the `root` directory, this is based on the location of the docker-compose.yml file
`dockerfile` is set to the name of the Dockerfile, in this case `Dockerfile`

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Great, I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Add the path to the docker file you want to include in your docker-compose.

For example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  dockerFileExample:
   build: ./Dockerfile // Or custom file name i.e. ./docker-file-frontend
```

Here is link to the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/